# Template is missing ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

localhost says that template is missing. routes.rb:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

     root 'home#index'

     resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

     get    'signup'   => 'users#new'
     get    'signin'   => 'sessions#new'
     delete 'signout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
     get    'about'    => 'static_pages#about'

     match '*path' => 'application#routing_error', via: :all

 end
```

nothing in my home_controller.rb

any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already have a **home** folder under **view**. If not, create the folder. Then add a **index.html.erb** with a heading like this:

```
 <h1>Welcome!</h1>
```

hope this helps

**edit**
You should define and index method too! (not necessary)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @YahsHef's answer.. You state that

> Nothing in my home_controller.rb

You'll also need the `index` method to exist.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

in order to render the view.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary if the method is empty.

Comment: it's necessary @AmrNoman, in order to render a view, you need an associated controller action.  In their case, `home#index`.  `home` is the controller, and `index` is the action. the action has to exist.

Comment: For me it always works if no action is defined, and the template exists!

Comment: If the action is not defined in the controller, it'll automatically map to a view, rails magic!